# Unity debug_WebGL_wasm/build.js failed with output issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl

I get the following error when trying to get webgl build in Unity game engine.

```
Building Library/Bee/artifacts/WebGL/build/debug_WebGL_wasm/build.js failed with output:
wasm-ld: error: function signature mismatch: init
>>> defined as (f64, i32) -> i32 in /var/folders/92/4kfx87317cx7bf1j1hl0554h0000gn/T/tmpi97470mbGameAssembly.a(zr6s_CSharp__10.o)
>>> defined as (i32, i32, i32, i32, i32) -> void in /var/folders/92/4kfx87317cx7bf1j1hl0554h0000gn/T/tmpi97470mbGameAssembly.a(j2cb_ity.Canvas.o)
emcc2: error: '/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.24f1/PlaybackEngines/WebGLSupport/BuildTools/Emscripten/llvm/wasm-ld @/var/folders/92/4kfx87317cx7bf1j1hl0554h0000gn/T/emscripten_1g4wee13.rsp.utf-8' failed (1)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

What I tried

- Deleting the last plugins and scripts I installed solves the problem, but I need those plugins and scripts.
- When I open a new project and add only the last plugins and scripts I added, I have no problem getting the build.

Comment: it would suggest those plugins arent suitable for webgl

Comment: You potentially have duplicate or conflicting plugins. Since you didn't tell us anything at all about what you're having trouble with the only advice I have is to systematically go through all of them and make sure the platforms are set correctly for inclusion in your build.

Comment: `function signature mismatch: init` sounds to me a bit like one of your plugins c# method doesn't match the according js plugin method signature ... If there are various Plugins in play I would try to add them one by one in order to figure out which one exactly is causing the issue ... Then nail it further down to the exact JS - c# script pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The conflicting package belonged to facebook sdk. The problem was solved when I uninstalled Facebook sdk.